# how to include several lines of C code in one line of source code (AVR-GCC)

Tags: c, avr-gcc

Is there a way to add an identifier that the compiler would replace with multiple lines of code?

I read up on macros and inline functions but am getting no where.

I need to write an Interrupt Service Routine and not call any functions for speed.
Trouble is I have several cases where I need to use a function so currently I just repeat all several lines in many places.

for example:

```
void ISR()
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;

// do some stuff here ...

  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;

// do more stuff here ...


  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
}
```

The function is many pages and I need the code to be more readable.

Comment: Have you verified that functions are slow? If you have a modern compiler and make the functions `static` and compile for speed it should automatically inline the code.

Comment: Many pages of code means the function is unreadable.  Small functions improve readability.  Measure the speed cost before you assume you can't use functions.  Using macros will decrease the readability — though it might make the code more compact as source.  It makes no difference to the end result, though; the macros will be expanded just as if you wrote. the information longhand.

Comment: if all the variables are int you can change   `int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;` to `int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;` And in general you can always put any two lines of code on the same physical line to make the code wider instead of longer.

Comment: You can always create an struct that package the list of variables that you want to create.

Comment: The a, b, c is just a hypothetical example. There is a complex 27 line chunk of code and several others that were once in a separate 'called' function which I pasted manual in place of the function call to get speed.

Comment: https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: If you want speed with a `avr-gcc` generated ISR written in C, make sure you observe the machine code actually generated. `-save-temps=obj` and `-Wa,-adhlns=$(@:.o=.lst)` and the generated `*.s` and `*.lst` files might be helpful here. Then look up what actual ISR entry/return takes for your particular AVR part. Then you can count which instruction takes how many cycles. Then you can check which instructions you do not actually need. And then you find out the actual hardware generating the interrupt takes 10 times the ISR time to reset and all that optimization was just a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - it is recommended that you not place function calls in an ISR. It's not that you cannot do it, but it can be a memory burden depending on the type of call. The primary reason is for timing. ISRs should be quick in and out. You shouldn't be doing a lot of extended work inside them.

That said, here's how you can actually use inline functions.

```
// In main.c
#include static_defs.h
//...
void ISR() {
    inline_func();
    // ...
    inline_func();
}

// In static_defs.h
static inline void inline_func(void) __attribute__((always_inline));

// ... Further down in file

static inline void inline_func(void) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The compiler will basically just paste the "do stuff" code into the ISR multiple times, but as I said before, if it's a complex function, it's probably not a good idea to do it multiple times in a single ISR, inlined or not. It might be better to set a flag of some sort and do it in your main loop so that other interrupts can do their job, too. Then, you can use a normal function to save program memory space. That depends on what you are really doing and when/why it needs done.

If you are actually setting variables and returning values, that's fine too, although, setting multiple variables would be done by passing/returning a structure or using a pointer to a structure that describes all of the relevant variables.

---

If you'd prefer to use macros (I wouldn't, because function-like macros should be avoided), here's an example of that:

```
#define RESET_VARS() do { \
     a = 1; \
     b = 2; \
     c = 3; \
  while (0)

//...

void ISR() {
   uint8_t a=1, b=2, c=3;
   RESET_VARS();
   // ...
   RESET_VARS();
}
```

---

Also, you said it was a hypothetical, but it's recommended to use the bit-width typedefs found in <stdint.h> (automatically included when you include <io.h> such as uint8_t rather than int. On an 8-bit MCU with AVR-GCC, an int is a 16-bit signed variable, which will require (at least) 2 clock cycles for every operation that would have taken one with an 8-bit variable.

Answer (score 4):

I basically agree with everyone else's reservations with regards to using macros for this.  But, to answer your question, Multiline macros can be created with a backslash.

```
#define INIT_VARS \
    int a = 1;    \
    int b = 2;    \
    int c = 3; 

#define RESET_VARS \
    a = 1;         \
    b = 2;         \
    c = 3; 

void ISR()
{    
    INIT_VARS
    // do some stuff here ...
    RESET_VARS
    // do more stuff here ...
    RESET_VARS
}
```

Comment: I have heard macros can cause issues from time to time when expansion occurs. I read one post where someone suggested a do while (0) loop {with braces to enclose all code}. would this work?

Comment: Defining macros like above so that you need to invoke them without `()` and without `;` looks confusing to people, and is confusing to many code editors. A well-used trick for multi-line macros is to wrap the actual statements inside a `do { ... } while (0)` block *without* the trailing semicolon. This macro you can now call as `MACRO();` or `MACRO(23, 42);` which looks like and behaves very much like a C function (except for the macro parameter substitution issues), which looks neater to people and causes less problems with editors (syntax highlighting, code indentation, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inline` function that will be rather integrated into place where it is called in source instead of really being called (note that behavior of this depends on several things like compiler support and optimizations setup or using `-fno-inline` flag feature). [GCC documentation on inline functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).

For completeness - other way would be defining `// do some stuff here...` as pre-processor macro which again gets inserted in place where called; this time by preprocessor - so no type safety, harder to debug and also to read. Usual good rule of thumb is to **not write a macro for something that can be done with function**.